# JavaScritpt: разница в методах задания строчных переменных

Tags: javascript

Имеют ли какие-нибудь технические различия следующие два метода задания строчных переменных в `JavaScrpit`?

```
// 1
var s1= "JavaScript";
// 2
var s2 = new String("JavaScript");
```

Comment: конечно есть, s2 будет объектом. s1 - строкой

Comment: [Разница между примитивом строки и объектом String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects)

Comment: @ Василий Барбашев, если так, то для `s1` не должен работать метод `.length`, а он работает, как будно `s1` - объект

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, не совсем так :)

Comment: А поподробнее? :)

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но length это **свойство** строки.

Comment: Когда интерпретатор обрабатывает инструкцию с литералом строки (или другого примитива), создаётся неявный объект этой строки. Существует он, обычно, текущую инструкцию, вроде как, поэтому присвоение свойства примитиву не вызовет ошибку, но этого свойства не будет в дальнейшем, т. к. создаётся новый объект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начать можно с [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects):

> ### Различие между примитивами строк и объектами строк
>
> **Важно:** в Javascript присутствуют различия между объектами строк и примитивами (Это верно и для *Boolean*, и *Number*)
>
> Литералы строк (обозначаяются двойными или одинарными кавычками) и строки возвращенный вызвом `String` в не-конструкторском контексте (т.е. без ключевого слова `new`) - примитивы строк.
>   Javascript автоматически конвертирует примитивы в объекты String, поэтому возможно использовать методы объекта String для примитивов строк. В ситуациях, когда для примитива строки нужно вызвать метод или найти свойство, Javascript автоматически обернет примитив в объект и вызовет нужный метод или свойство.

```js
var s_prim = 'foo';
var s_obj = new String(s_prim);

console.log(typeof s_prim); // Logs "string"
console.log(typeof s_obj); // Logs "object"
```

Примитивы строк и объекты строк, имеют различие при использовании `eval()`.
Примитивы переданные в `eval` будут обработаны как исходный код; Объекты строк будут обработаны как и все другие объекты, возвращением самого себя, например:

```js
var s1 = '2 + 2'; // creates a string primitive
var s2 = new String('2 + 2'); // creates a String object
console.log(eval(s1)); // returns the number 4
console.log(eval(s2), s2 === eval(s2)); // returns the string "2 + 2"
```

Поэтому код может сломаться, если получит на вход объект String, вместо ожидаемого примитива строка, однако, обычно не нужно беспокоиться о различиях.

у строки-объекта всегда можно получить соответствующий ей примитив, с помощью вызова метода [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf).

Кроме того: литералы неизменяемы, поэтому, в отличие от объектов им нельзя добавить новых свойств, а так же их сравнение происходит как сравнение объектов

```js
var primitive_s = '123';
var primitive_s2 = '123'
var s1 = new String('123');
var s2 = new String('123');

primitive_s.prop = 10;
console.log('primitive_s.prop', primitive_s.prop);
s1.prop = 10;
console.log('s1.prop', s1.prop);

console.log(primitive_s == primitive_s2, primitive_s === primitive_s2);

console.log(s1 == s2, s1 === s2);

// но!

console.log(primitive_s == s1, primitive_s === s2);
```

<sup>примеры на основе ответов: [первый](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24320766/2881286), [второй](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36614897/2881286)</sup>

---

### С точки зрения [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getvalue)

При получении значения свойства, в случае примитивного объекта вызывается абстрактная функция [ToObject](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toobject). У результата вызывается нужное свойство с нужным this.

---

### С точки зрения реализации.

Спецификация никак не ограничивает как должны быть реализованы примитивы и объекты. А так же не регламентирует наличие/отсутствие свойств у примитивов.

Например, для V8

Строковые примитивы разбираются в объект класса [v8::String](http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1String.html). Следовательно методы могут быть вызваны напрямую у этого объекта.

Строки-объекты, в свою очередь, разбираются в объекты класса [v8::StringObject](http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1StringObject.html), который расширяет класс `Object` и будучи полноценным объектом служит оболочкой для `v8::String`.

<sup>этот пункт частичный перевод [ответа на английский вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17256419/2881286)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Строковые литералы (обозначаемые двойными или одинарными кавычками) и строки, возвращённые вызовом `String` в неконструкторном контексте (то есть, без использования ключевого слова new) являются строковыми примитивами. JavaScript автоматически преобразует примитивы в объекты `String`, так что на строковых примитивах возможно использовать методы объекта `String`. В контекстах, когда на примитивной строке вызывается метод или происходит поиск свойства, JavaScript автоматически оборачивает строковый примитив объектом и вызывает на нём метод или ищет в нём свойство.

```
var s_prim = 'foo';
var s_obj = new String(s_prim);

console.log(typeof s_prim); // выведет 'string'
console.log(typeof s_obj);  // выведет 'object'
```

Строковые примитивы и объекты `String` также дают разные результаты при использовании глобальной функции `eval()`. Примитивы, передаваемые в `eval()`, трактуются как исходный код; объекты же `String` трактуются так же, как и все остальные объекты, а именно: возвращается сам объект. Например:

```
var s1 = '2 + 2';             // создаёт строковый примитив
var s2 = new String('2 + 2'); // создаёт объект String
console.log(eval(s1));        // выведет число 4
console.log(eval(s2));        // выведет строку '2 + 2'
```

Источник - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: А ссылка на источник? https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects

Comment: @Other забыл, добавил)