# Как работают объекты ООП в JS?

Tags: javascript, ооп, объекты, теория

Почитав десяток другой статей об ООП в JS попытался подытожить то, что понял.

Получается создавая переменную  `let i = 3` конструктор берет свойства и методы из прототипов объекта `number`?

Или что-то не так?

Comment: Да, совершено верно, в дальнейшем при интерпетации, удаляется сам объект от числа, соответственно доступа к прототипу также не будет.

Comment: Но остаеться доступ к методам и свойствам?

Comment: Он есть, потому что по сути примтивы это обьекты с метоадми и свойствами которые получили резе прототипы, но в дальнейшем обьекты у примитивных типов удаляются, вот подробнее https://learn.javascript.ru/native-prototypes#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [JavaScritpt: разница в методах задания строчных переменных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591547/javascritpt-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При необходимости вызова метода относительно примитива интерпретатор заворачивает значение в объект-обертку, результатом может быть другой примитив, а на временную "обертку" не остается никаких ссылок и сборщик мусора ее чуть позже где-то в тишине прикончит...

То есть `0.004.toFixed(2)` неявно превратится в `(new Number(0.004)).toFixed(2)`.

Comment: в зависимости от реализации временной обертки может и не быть

Comment: @Grundy, это поведение никак не закреплено в стандарте? Смог найти лишь косвенные отсылки, вроде вызова от `null`/`undefined`

Comment: Стандарт описывает семантику, это не совсем то же самое что жесткое руководство по реализации. По моему тут был где-то ответ, про v8

Comment: вот немного похожий вопрос:[JavaScritpt: разница в методах задания строчных переменных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591629/186999)

Comment: @free_ze, стандарт описывает отсутствие обёртки в strict-режиме. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435547/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, только для значений null/undefined, как я и говорил - это в спеке [есть](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-strict-mode-of-ecmascript)) Интересуют остальные случаи или хотя бы умолчательное поведение.

Answer (score 0):

Конструктор ниоткуда ничего не берёт.

При обращении к свойствам и методам срабатывает стандартная схема поиска по цепочке прототипов. Когда метод находится, в зависимости от того, написан ли он в строгом режиме, число либо оборачивается в объект, либо передаётся в `this` как есть.

Впрочем, некоторое время назад некоторые браузеры были неприспособлены к такому поведению и выполняли обёртывание в объект всегда. Кажется, сейчас везде исправлено.

```js
var a = 1, b = Number(2), c = new Number(3)

console.log(typeof a, typeof b, typeof c)

Number.prototype.nonStrictFunc = function () {
  return this
}

Number.prototype.strictFunc = function () {
  'use strict'
  return this
}

console.log(typeof a.nonStrictFunc(), typeof b.nonStrictFunc(), typeof c.nonStrictFunc())
console.log(typeof a.strictFunc(), typeof b.strictFunc(), typeof c.strictFunc())
```